# How to find a particular key and replace the value in shell script?

Tags: sed, json

I have a JSON file with the following text

```
{"category": "yyy", "id": "xxxyyy", "environment": "fff", "client": "000000", "user": "Alex", "log_time": "xxx", "source_context": null}
```

I need to find the the key `user` in that file and replace its value `Alex` with `XXXX` with exactly the same size (`Alex` = `XXXX`, `Tom` = `XXX`). I tried with `sed` command but I couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't parse JSON data with text oriented parser like `sed`. Instead use a JSON aware parser like `jq`.

If this tool is available on your system, you could simple do:

```
 jq '.user |= gsub(".";"X")' file
```

That replaces all string for the key `user` with the same number of `X` characters.

If your `jq` doesn't support `gsub`, you may use something like this:

```
jq '.user |= ([range(0;length)]|.[]="X"|add)' file
```

Comment: It also requires that `jq` is compiled with support for `sub` and related regular expression functions. The default (at least on some systems) is to not include support for these functions :-(  Apart from that, this is probably the best approach (using a proper JSON parser, not `sed` etc.)

Comment: Like you said, gsub is not supported. I get the following error.
error: gsub is not defined
.user |= gsub(".";"X")
         ^^^^
1 compile error
Can you please help in fixing it ?

Comment: @user2181698 Answer updated. I hope that your version will support used functions...

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the following error

error: too few arguments to range (expected 2 but got 1)
.user |= ([range(length)]|.[]="X"|add)
               ^^^^^

Comment: @user2181698 What version of `jq` do you have?? Anyway try with `jq '.user |= ([range(0;length)]|.[]="X"|add)' file`...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. One more help on this. How to use this command to replace all instances of the key 'def' 's value from "I want this" to "XXXXX" in this snippet.



[{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John",
    "aux": [{
        "abc": "random",
        "def": "I want this" 
    }],
    "blah": 23.11
}]

Comment: @user2181698 Please avoid changing the scope of the question. Instead ask a new question stating the problem you've encountered.